# Activating virtual environment through airflow

Tags: airflow

I have created an R job and have placed it on a server. I am using airflow to schedule that R job. All my R libraries are placed in a virtual environment created on the server. I have a bash script which has the reference of my R job I want to schedule.
I am facing an issue with activating the virtual environment.

Comment: Could you please provide some example of what you tried and you got as errors?

Comment: what's the issue? what's the error message if you get any? show us your code ,